# How to access the .as file Variable in .Fla File?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a function(initialize) inside the a.as File.i want to access the that  Variable from aaa.fla file?.How Can i access the Variable?my main class is a.as file ,inside a.as file i load the aaa.swf file
AnyBody Help me
Thanks in advance!

```
public function initialize(parameters:Object, stage:Stage, 
     loaderInfo:LoaderInfo, pluginHostWhitelist:Array):void
    {
        sourceId=loaderInfo.parameters.src;
        addText();//Inside this function i load the aaa.swf file,
        //here i want to access the variable "sourceId"
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

 addText(){
_loader.load(new URLRequest("aaa.swf"));//while running this a.as i want to get the Sourceid Value
 mainContainer.addChild(_loader);   
    }
```

My aaa.fla   Its in Another place

```
import fl.motion.ColorMatrix;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;
var sourceId:String// here i want to access the "sourceid" variable from a.as file
trace(sourceId)
```

Comment: What do you mean the value is not passed? You need to make sure the value exist...check edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--------------------------  start edit -----------------------------------

A .fla file is a Flash IDE document!

Where does your sourceId variable come from?

In your example, it seems to come from flashvars, meaning that you would get the value from your SWF embedding code.

If this is the case, this wouldn't be relevant in your .fla file, because you wouldn't load an external swf using HTML embedded code.

Let's forget about flashvars for the time being... Are you using a Document Class with your .fla file? If not, I would advise you to, it'd make coding a lot easier. If yes, I suppose that you would load the external SWF there.

In the external SWF you could event use Custom Event Dispatching to pass your vars...

```
    //in your external SWF
    private function onAddedToStage( event:Event ):void
    {
        //you could use a Custom Event
        //do some research on AS3 custom events... 
        var idEvent:YourEvent = new YourEvent();
        idEvent.sourceId = sourceID;

        this.dispatchEvent( idEvent );
    }


     //then in your .fla's Document Class
     private var sourceId:Object;

     private function addExternalSwf( event:Event ):void
     {
          var external:MovieClip = event.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
          external.addEventListener( YourEvent.SOURCE_ID , idEventListener );
          addChild( external );

          //remove addExternalSwf listener here...
     }

     private function idEventListener( event:YourEvent ):void
     {
          sourceId = event.sourceId;
          //remove idEventListener listener here...
     }
```

----------------------  end edit -----------------------------

Your question is really not clear... I can only go by the code example you give

```
public function initialize(parameters:Object, stage:Stage, 
           loaderInfo:LoaderInfo, pluginHostWhitelist:Array):void
{
    //here you're retrieving the sourceID variable
    //from the loaded SWF
    sourceId=loaderInfo.parameters.src;

    //Inside this function i load the a.swf file, 
    //here i want to access the variable "sourceId"...???

    if( sourceId != null )
         addText( sourceId );
    else
         trace('sourceID has a null value!!!!');

    //why do you remove the event listener here
    //and not within the onAddedToStage method???
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function addText(sourceId:Object):void
{
     //....
}
```

Comment: Hai Patrick i want to get the variable "sourceid" in aaa.fla,But in addText() just i load the aaa.swf file.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, and I won't get into all of them.

But the easiest way is probably to cast your loaded SWF to Object (which is a dynamic class, so it will accept unknown member names) and add the property there, like so (I assume you use a Loader to load it, since you haven't posted the actual loading code):

```
Object(loader.content).sourceId = sourceId;
```

or you could also use bracket syntax:

```
loader.content["sourceId"] = sourceId;
```

The loaded SWF then doesn't need to know anything about outside classes and can use its own variable.  The only thing you have to take care of is that either a) the SWFs base class is a dynamic class, such as MovieClip, or b) if you have a non-dynamic base class, make sure it has a public variable or setter method called `sourceId`.

If you need more compilation time type checking, you can also have your SWF implement an interface and cast to that interface instead of Object.

Comment: hai weltraumpirat i Can't get the sourceId value kindly help me

Comment: i Cannot Get Plz Guide me Shall i Send my Full Code.or Any more Explanation

Comment: I can't work through all of your project.  Start with the part where the error occurs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4860/discussion-between-user996753-and-weltraumpirat)

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is worded, it's hard to be sure what yo're really asking, but it seems to me that you're looking for a way to get the sourceId variable into the loaded swf.

First I should explain that trying to read it from within the swf is bad practice--child objects should not know about parent objects.  So I'm not going to answer the question as asked.

One thing you may not be aware of is that DisplayObject has access to its own loaderInfo property, so you probably don't need to get this value from the outside in this specific instance.

As a more general matter, you can expose a public property on the document Class you use in the swf, and then you can cast the loaderInfo.content to that Class and then set that property to sourceId from the function in the parent.

Comment: Thank You for Kind Replying here my function initialize is a.as file inside my as file,i added a.swf.Now i Want to pass the variable sourceId into a.swf.My Question is Clear?

Comment: @user996753: Your question is clear, you're just going at this the wrong way around.  It is bad practice to let your loaded SWF know about things on the outside.  Instead, pass the variable directly to the SWF, so it only needs to know about itself.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: You should never cast to the loaded SWFs base class, because then you will bloat your loader code with everything that is imported and used in the loaded SWF.  To have loose coupling along with type safety, it is always best to use interfaces instead.

Comment: @weltraumpirat Is the question clear? It looks like the op is using flashvars, therefore I'm not quite sure what the exact problem is :)

Comment: I wouldn't say "never" on this.  It depends on what the base Class is and what it is doing.  If it only is taking the value in the Getter and setting a label text, for instance, it's probably not going to cause that much bloat. It seems to me the OP is a beginner, and it might be that Interfaces are something he's not ready for yet (and the question can be answered without them).

Comment: @Amy: I agree, that's why I suggested doing it without importing anything from the SWF ;)

Comment: @PatrickS: The way I read it, he's using FlashVars in the **loader** SWF.  But you're right: He could pass them on as GET parameters, as well.

Comment: @weltraumpirat You probably right, the OP question seems a bit over complicated to me , loading a variable from a SWF and passing the value to another object without creating dependency can also be achieved with Events. He may get a clearer answer by re-phrasing the question. These a.as a.swf a.fla are rather confusing as it seems the OP is talking about a single Object!